# How to keep original field name in Request Facade ($request) data when submit form in Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, input, request, sql-update

I am working with existed SQL Server Database that most table field names have space. Example: **Family Name**

In my update view file. I have created field name with space as well (**Family Name**) to match with table field name.

When I try to update the model I got the problem with `$request->all()` method, because **Request facade** convert the input field name from `Family Name` to **`Family_Name`**. so I have to manually write the updating code in very fields that I got

```
$trainee    = Trainee::findOrFail($id);

$trainee->{'Family Name'}   = $request->input('Family_Name');
$trainee->{'Sex'}           = $request->input('Sex');
.......                     = ........

$trainee->save();
```

**instead of**

```
$trainee    = Trainee::findOrFail($id);

$input = $request->all();
$trainee->fill($input)->save();
```

**IT IS A HUGE PAIN** as I need to write many line of code repeatedly instead of using `$input = $request->all();`

---

**Question:**

How to prevent Request Facade from converting the input field name from `Family Name` to `Family_Name`?

Comment: space are not allowed that is why it is converting the same.

Comment: Also go through this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1065295/SQL-Server-Table-and-Column-Naming-Conventions)

Comment: You're trying to solve the problem on the wrong side.  what keeps you from renaming the database scheme and migrate the data?

Comment: @GlennPlas, Because this project is designing new Front-End of existed Database that already having 2 years data. Client want the new Web-Based Front-End with the same Schema Structure. So I cannot change anything on the schema.

Comment: @Jigs1212, thanks for your comment. I have found the alternative soluton. I will update in the answer.

Comment: you can rename the columns though but considering the naming conventions will help in future.

Comment: @Jigs1212, yes I always follow the Laravel Standard Naming Conventions in all my projects. But project & Schema Field Name Conventions was built by other developer, that leave me no choice

Comment: well, you better not run a `migrate:refresh` on this database when you have done everything `laravelish`.  good luck

Comment: @GlennPlas, Thanks. I will keep in mind.